# TDD a CRUD application complex Database Design

Tags: jakarta-ee, tdd, dao

We are assigned to develop a software system. It almost lacks any business logic but simple CRUD operations (and some little controls on some of forms).
But the problem is the data-model already exists and it is irrelevant to the UI forms. I mean each form just maps to multiple tables, or multiple columns on multiple tables.

I believe we shall design the Object (entity - or DTOs) model according to business logic and not the complex legacy database design. So the application remains easy and understandable, and wrap all the complexity behind a set of Data Access Objects.

This leads to complex DAO objects, which are the most important target of the test. Is it possible to write tests for DAO objects without a database? How?

Comment: Any reason you can't use simple unit tests for this? Provide some mocked entity data, set expectations for UI model data. Nothing stopping you writing the tests first.

Comment: Aren't the tests you mentioned integration/functional tests?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a layer of indirection.

DAOs are tested using integration tests against a real data store, since those tests check the DAOs ability to perform those queries successfully.

The missing layer, then, would be the translation layer between the old model and the new model. That layer can easily be unit tested, and should only contain pure functions that convert between the two.

This would leave the DAOs simple and easily testable, and make the conversion layer much easier to test too.